# How to replace a specific index inside of an array with a new string, and then revert it back to its original value?

Tags: python

```
gameMap = [['.'] * 5 for _ in xrange(5)]   # '.' represents grass.
```

This should print something along the lines of:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

I'm looking to replace a specific index of this array using the tracked user position.  If the user position is at `(0, 0)`, i.e. `userpos = gamemap[0][0]`, and I replace that index with a `'P'` so the first row looked like `[['P', '.', '.', '.', '.'],`, how would I go about tracking that index's original value of `'.'` so that when the player moves from 0,0 I could replace the that tile with its first value, which in this case would be `'.'`?

Answer (score 3):

Just save the old value in a variable, e.g. `player_room_char`:

```
player_room_char = gameMap[i][j]
gameMap[i][j] = 'P'

...

gameMap[i][j] = player_room_char
```

Presumably there is only one player, so you should only need a single variable.